# .animate(scrollTop) moving at different speeds

Tags: jquery, html

I have a scrollable div that I want to reach the bottom of the text within after 35.5 seconds.  However, there seems to be some difference in the rate at which it hits the bottom on different devices.  I use animate(scrollTop) to hide the height of the entire div after 35 seconds.

Any idea as to why it might be different on a phone vs. a tablet?

```
var scrollTime = 35500;
var scroller = $("#scroller");


setTimeout(function() {
    startScrolling(scroller, scrollTime);
}, 2000);


function startScrolling(scroller_obj, scrollTime) {
    var ht = $('.scrollingtext').height();

    scroller_obj.animate({scrollTop: ht}, scrollTime);
    scroller_obj.animate({scrollTop: 0}, 10);

    scroller_obj.on('touchstart click', function() {
        scroller_obj.stop( true, false );
    });
}
```

EDIT: Had to re-add some deleted code.

Comment: Is there an actual difference in time, or does it just look slower?

Comment: There is an actual difference in time.  If I start it on two different devices at the same time (I just tried an iPad vs. an iPhone) the larger one finishes much quicker than the smaller.  I just clocked the iPad finishing at about 21 seconds vs. the iPhone taking the full 35.

Comment: iPhones pause Javascript execution during scrolling to preserve battery power. The slowdown you experience on a cell phone vs. tablet is likely a result of this. Also, unless you are running a timeOut function that is actually time based, the speed of any Javascript animation you run is going to be impacted by the rendering engine, processor power, and whether what you are doing relies on JS or not (on cell). Here is an extensive writeup on this issue.

http://developer.telerik.com/featured/scroll-event-change-ios-8-big-deal/